# Flutter plugin that configures notification overrides the configuration done in application's native side. IOS

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am  handling notifications from two SDKs , one of the SDKs namely Sendibrd_chat_sdk is written in dart and I am using flutter_local_notification package to handle notifications from, in parallel I have Sendbird_call_sdk written in swift configured as IOS native sdk and trying to handle the notifications from native swift, my swift code is written in /iOS folder of the application itself.

Problem is as soon as I have flutter_local_notification instantiated in flutter, IOS configuration of notifications written by me does not work anymore for the call_sdk it seems to be overridden by flutter_local_notification plugin.

I have 3-fold question:

1. I would like to confirm that it really is a known case for the IOS cause I seem to not be able to find any question or answer about this issue anywhere.(Part of the reason why I am writing it here)?
2. Is there any known solution for this ?
3. Would the behaviour persisted, if had created custom plugin and had moved my code from applications iOS folder into the custom plugins iOS folder ?

Thank you in advance.